# How to find out do I have NAND Flash or NOR flash (Compact Flash)

Tags: compact-flash

How to find out do I have NAND Flash or NOR flash (Compact Flash)

I have Transcend UDMA 300x 2Gb. No mention is it NAND or NOR flash

Comment: Have you looked at the technical specifications of your device?

Comment: @TomWijsman yes, and there is no info about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOR flash is byte-addressable.  It's usually used in applications where a CPU needs to execute code from it directly, like BIOS or boot ROM firmware.

NAND works in blocks somewhat like disks.  So generally anything else, especially in memory card or storage device situations, is going to be NAND.  Some NAND has a "Disk On Chip" mode where block 0 can be executed directly, but not any other blocks.

You could always open up the card and run any numbers on ICs you find within through Google to absolutely confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your particular CF, it is NAND Flash chip. Look [here](http://www.transcend-info.com/Press/index.asp?LangNo=0&axn=Detail&PrsNo=969&NewsKeyWd=&Func1No=6&Func2No=219&Func3No=), press release of Transcend's 300X CompactFlash cards.

And if you are interested in finding if CF is NAND/NOR google keyword for you is **MTD**.

Maybe somehow you can find the chip used by the flash. And then you can search for that chip if that chip is NAND or NOR.